# Form input value for preview link

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

Hi I'm trying to build a form (not important but only to know: in bootstrap 5) with several fields and on one of these, where a url will be inserted, capture the value written inside and launch that page in a new tab, all before the form submission.

For the basic function it's ok, but I would like the <a href tag to be "disabled"(not clickable) as long as it is empty and starts working when someone writes into it.
Could you give me some tips?

This is the code:

Html:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-md" style="margin:10px;padding:10px 0 0 0;">
  <label for="fUrl"><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i>URL</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="255" id="fUrl" name="fUrl" value="">
    <span class="input-group-text">
      <a href="" target="_blank" id="HreffUrl" onclick="changeHrefCol()" title="Anteprima">A</a>
    </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function changeHrefCol(){
        // Selecting the input element and get its value 
        let inputVal = document.getElementById("fUrl").value;
        if(inputVal !== null && inputVal !== '') {
            // Set it for the href
            document.getElementById("HreffUrl").setAttribute("href", `${inputVal}`);
        } 
        // Test
        console.log(inputVal);
    }
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/berettatim/pen/MWVvYyo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By attaching the `input` event listener to the input field you can change the `.href` immediately when the input changes. And when the input is empty (`this.value.length==0`)
you can remove the `.href` attribute altogether, making it "unclickable".

```js
const a=document.getElementById("HreffUrl");
document.getElementById("fUrl").addEventListener("input",function(){
 if(this.value.length)
  a.href=this.value;
 else a.removeAttribute("href");
 console.log(a.href);
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group form-group-md" style="margin:10px;padding:10px 0 0 0;">
  <label for="fUrl"><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i>URL</label>
  <div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="255" id="fUrl" name="fUrl" value="">
<span class="input-group-text">
  <a target="_blank" id="HreffUrl" title="Anteprima">A</a>
</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 Note that a missing `href` attribute not only makes the element unclickable, but also denotes that ["the element represents a placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).